# Unable to scan properly with details for high resolution stamp

Tags: adobe-photoshop, scanning

I am trying to scan a postal stamp which has some really tiny fonts and very neat details. No matter how hard I try I can not able to catch those details and colors in the scanned image. I have tried the highest possible resolution with my [HP Scanjet 300](http://www8.hp.com/emea_africa/en/products/scanners/product-detail.html?oid=5251707) and [Cannon LiDE 200](http://www.canon.co.uk/scanners/flatbed-scanners/canoscan_lide_200/)

I am on Mac and have scanned with the native scanning software as well as trying to scan with Photoshop. Can't seem to figure out what I am doing wrong. The colors and the details just don't look good in the scanned image. The stamp is on a usual glossy paper.

Any suggestions/pointers would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe you could attach an image so we can figure out what the problem might be.

Answer (score 1):

Postage stamps are just too tiny to get a good scan with a flatbed scanner.

I suggest you photograph it instead.

You might also make sure it will be legal, depending on your purpose. I'd check the laws regarding reproduction of postage stamps. [Here's a link.](https://www.avvo.com/legal-answers/reproducing--for-sale--artwork-that-includes-the-u-18347.html)

"Most government work is not subject to copyright but stamps are. There is a licensing division of the US Postal Service that deals with this specifically."